# Problem with loading image from bytes array

Tags: c#, wpf

I encountered strange behaviour when loading image from byte array aquired from stream. Most images are correct, I would say 99% of them. But i saw so far two times something like this below. Image in the middle is shown like a set of random pixels, not the real image.

Image can be loaded correctly in other client application (sliverlight) but i can't show that.
In WPF client i have something like that:

[image: Image in the middle is shown like a set of random pixels,]

Does someone had issue like this? Or any idea what might cause it? Maybe i should look on server side (image is show in other, older client and code to load that is known to me).

Code looks like that:

```
    public async Task<ImageCreatePictureBox> CreatePictureBox(IBaseObj pmIBaseObj, IObj pmObj)
    {
        var lcContainer = new Grid
        {
            Width = pmObj.PresObj.Width,
            Height = pmObj.PresObj.Height
        };
        var gridBorder = new Border();

        CustomImg imageControl = null;
        FrameworkElement lcFrameworkElement = lcContainer;

        if (!(pmIBaseObj is ImageBaseObj lcImageBaseObj))
            return new ImageCreatePictureBox(null, lcContainer, lcFrameworkElement, pmObj);

        if (!lcImageBaseObj.CustomBitMap)
        {
            try
            {
                var bitmapImage = BitmapImageHelper.ByteArrayToBitmapSource(lcImageBaseObj.Image, lcImageBaseObj.ImageWidth, lcImageBaseObj.ImageHeight);

                imageControl = new CustomImg(pmIBaseObj.Width, pmIBaseObj.Height, pmObj)
                {
                    Source = bitmapImage,
                    Height = lcImageBaseObj.Height,
                    Width = lcImageBaseObj.Width
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Helper.GetPathToImage("dummy")));
                imageControl = new CustomImg(pmIBaseObj.Width, pmIBaseObj.Height, pmObj)
                {
                    Source = src,
                    Height = lcImageBaseObj.Height,
                    Width = lcImageBaseObj.Width
                };
                Helper.WriteToDebug(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var bitmapImage = BitmapImageHelper.ByteArrayToBitmapSource(lcImageBaseObj.Image, lcImageBaseObj.ImageWidth, lcImageBaseObj.ImageHeight);

                imageControl = new CustomImg(pmIBaseObj.Width, pmIBaseObj.Height, pmObj)
                {
                    Source = bitmapImage,
                    Height = lcImageBaseObj.Height,
                    Width = lcImageBaseObj.Width
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (imageControl == null)
                    imageControl = new CustomImg(pmIBaseObj.Width, pmIBaseObj.Height, pmObj);
                var src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Helper.GetPathToImage("dummy")));
                imageControl = new CustomImg(pmIBaseObj.Width, pmIBaseObj.Height, pmObj)
                {
                    Source = src,
                    Height = lcImageBaseObj.Height,
                    Width = lcImageBaseObj.Width
                };
                Helper.WriteToDebug(e);
            }
        }

        (...)
        
        return new ImageCreatePictureBox(imageControl, lcContainer, lcFrameworkElement, pmObj);
    }



    public static BitmapSource ByteArrayToBitmapSource(Byte[] BArray, int imgWidth, int imgHeight)
    {
        try
        {
            var width = imgWidth;
            var height = imgHeight;
            var dpiX = 90d;
            var dpiY = 90d;
            var pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Pbgra32;
            var bytesPerPixel = (pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
            var stride = bytesPerPixel * width;

            var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, dpiX, dpiY, pixelFormat, null, BArray, stride);
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BytesToBitmapImage(BArray);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it works 99% of the time, I would expect it to be some difference between the 1% that fail, and the 99% that works. Are you sure the source data is correct?

Comment: @JonasH, i think it's fine because in older version of software written in Silverlight there is no issue like it, every image is shown properly.

But maybe i should verify it once more, how it's made there, and how is data send/received.

Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It does not matter in this specific case, but the stride should be calculated as `stride = (width * pixelFormat.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;`

Comment: Besides that, please try to remove the irrelevant parts of your code. I guess we don't need to see the ImageCreatePictureBox class and a lot of other stuff.

Comment: It's also unclear why you create the BitmapSource with 90 DPI instead of the standard 96.